# How to use Symfony Process with Python /w variables

Tags: python, laravel, symfony

I'm trying to change my code from using the PHP method `shell_exec()` to the Symfony Component Process.

Currently, I am using as: `$result = shell_exec("python3 \path\to\python.py var1 var2 var3");` to execute my python file in my laravel project.

I cannot find any way to add the `var1 var2 var3` with Symfony's process. Either I am blind and can't read the doc properly, or I can't do what I need to do with Symfony Process.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to provide arguments as an array

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(['python3', '\path\to\python.py', 'var1', 'var2', 'var3']);
```

Comment: This works on my local server, I will attempt to replicated it on my production server. Thank you. Will update if needed, if not, will approve this as answer.

Comment: A follow-up question, does the entire Symfony package deal with Python modules, or is downloading them still required?

Comment: Using a Python module is nothing more than calling a terminal command, and Symfony Process is nothing more than calling a terminal command in an object way. So yeah you still have to download them.