# Run python script from larave framework

Tags: python, laravel, symfony-process

Hi everyone who i can i pass laravel parameter with symfony process code i use it to run python script

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process; 
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException; 
 
$process = new Process(['python3','/path/to/your_script.py',$policyname); 
$process->run();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726532/how-to-use-symfony-process-with-python-w-variables

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can pass laravel parameter to python.

1. You need to install symfony/process using following command:

   ```
   composer require symfony/process
   ```
2. you can use it in laravel as

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
   use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

   $process = new Process(['python', '/path/to/script.py']);
   $process->run();

   // error handling
   if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
      throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
   }

   $output_data = $process->getOutput();
   ```

If you want to pass parameters to python, do this:

```
$process = new Process(['python', '/path/to/script.py', $arg]);
```